# Individually meaningful building block of a complex word

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

If there is a complex word that consists of two simpler words, what would you call each component, or individually meaningful building block, that the big word consists of, relative to the big word?

E.g., the word ***makeshift*** consists of the words *make* and *shift*.  What would you call each of those two words relative to *makeshift*?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_(linguistics)

Comment: Try the linguistics stackexchange beta site.

Comment: The smallest meaningful element in a word is called a *morpheme*. But endings and affixes also count as morphemes. I think the smallest elements that are in no way affixes or endings are the *roots* or *stems* of words (subtle distinction, depends on how you look at it).

Comment: There seems to be no official term that exclusively describes it, but *constituent* of the compound, *element* of the compound should serve adequately.

Comment: @RegDwighт Wiki uses both *constituent* and *element*, but only in a general sense. I could not yet find a GR source that names a "constituent element of a compound word", if there's a term for it. I am not done with the search, though.

Comment: @Kris: wiki uses *constituent* and *(radical) element* precisely because there's nothing wrong with using them — as you say yourself in your penultimate comment. More to the point, wiki doesn't stop at that. It explains *head* and *modifier*, it defines *primary verb* and *explicator*, it has dedicated entries for *morpheme* and *lexeme*, *stem* and *root*. It offers a wealth of information, all accessible from that one central article I linked to. If none of that suits the OP, he should specify why. That's something we try to enforce across the board, not just with this one question.

Comment: I don't see how that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are referred as " Morphemes ". 
 They are the smallest grammatical unit, like molecules of grammar elements. 
 You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_morpheme)